# Convert XAML Binding to C#

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, code-behind

I am building some dynamic controls and would like to convert the following XAML to C#...

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=GridGroup1, Path=ActualHeight}">
```

The above forms part of a dynamically built Border control that I would like to set so that it has the same height as a dynamically built Grid.

Any ideas on how I can do this please? All the examples I have found seem to be incomplete.

Thanks,

Paul.

Amendment... Ok here is the complete XAML...

```
<Grid x:Name="GridGroup1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="20,14,0,0"
                  Width="250"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="{StaticResource PanelBackground}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource PanelBorderBrush}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="0,8,0,0"
                        Width="250"
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=GridGroup1, Path=ActualHeight}">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect />
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
```

Comment: No way to answer this without seeing the rest of the XAML -- for the control in question at the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = GridGroup1;
    binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight");
    MyGridBorder.SetBinding(Border.HeightProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Yep, MSDN says pretty much the same: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx